# (Nuxt)npm run dev have wrong，node_modules error

Tags: vue-cli, nuxt.js

First of all
Please forgive me for not good English, I am using google translation.

Recently just got to work, I want to turn the code in the company into localhost, which is more convenient to develop.

I don't know what happened. 
I tried removing node_modules and reinstalling.I also tried **npm rebuild node-sass**, I still don't know where there is a problem.

```
Failed to compile with 19 errors:                                                                    
                                                                                                          These relative modules were not found:
* ../../../../../../../../../assets/img/icon/clock.svg in 
./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-
loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??
ref--7-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-oneOf-1-
3!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-
options!./pages/_catName/vendorList/_location_id/index.vue?
vue&type=style&index=0&id=2e9c7704&lang=scss&scoped=true&
```

...
...
And so on

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoKYr.png)

[my package.josn(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u29xv.png)

[my package.josn(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzLnV.png)

[my package.josn(3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZwOJ.png)

Comment: You are probably importing some file with the wrong relative path in one of your modules (`../../../../../../../../../assets/img/icon/clock.svg` seems the one causing problems here)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not clear but I guess you need to install css-loader first before using style-loader. Try :

```
npm install --save-dev style-loader
```

after that use style-loader and css-loader together in your config.js file. For example:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: it comes out of the box in nuxt